# replace string dynamically in resource file

Tags: c#, bootbox, resource-files

In my cshtml page i have one bootbox dialog like this

```
bootbox.dialog({
                  title: "Addresstitle " + ADDRESS + " save",
                  message: "you will be send to " + fromaddress + "for verification dear" + customer,
                  buttons: {
                   success: {
                                label: "Next,
                                className: "btn btn-success",
                                callback: function(){
                                      //some logic
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

I will create 2 resource string in resource file one for title and one for message

```
Addresstitle {0} save
you will be send to {0} for {1} verification dear {2}
```

How can i set this text in resource file  dynamically?

Comment: use string.Format in your cshtml to replace resource text placeholders ({0}, {1}....) - if the values are available on server side. If your ADDRESS, formaddress and customer are JavaScript vars/props then you will need to do it in JavaScript.

Comment: Is ADDRESS Modal Property?

Comment: @UdaraKasun yes its from knockout.

Comment: @IMujagic yes they are javascript var but how to replace it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your project structure but here is the high level idea how to do solve this:

1. You store your strings to some resource C# class called `Resources` ($TITLE$, $FORM$ and $CUSTOMER$ are placeholders that will be replaced later in JS):

   - Key: **Title** Value: Addresstitle **$TITLE$** save
   - Key: **Message** Value: you will be send to **$FORM$** for verification dear **$CUSTOMER$**.
2. In your Razor page where you prepare the view you can also provide your server side resources as a JS object within your view so that browser/JavaScript can also use them:

```
<script>
  var resourceObj = {
      title: '@Resources.Title',
      message: '@Resources.Message'
  }
</script>
```

3. Once the view is loaded in the browser, you can use JavaScript to access that JS object and set the dialog title and message:

```
bootbox.dialog({
   title: resourceObj.title.replace("$TITLE$", ADDRESS),
   message: resourceObj.message.replace("$FORM$", fromaddress).replace("$CUSTOMER$", customer),
   buttons: {
       success: {
           label: "Next,
           className: "btn btn-success",
           callback: function(){
               //some logic
           }
       }
   }
});
```

`resourceObj` is part of the JS global namespace in this example just to make everything simpler.

Comment: i get error when fetching resourcefile into resouceObj. It says unexpected identifier

Comment: I have edited my answer. I think, you have to put resourceObj prop values under single quotation marks..